# Comparing tables and getting non matching values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm pretty new to SQL and I can't get this to work I've got these two tables below

```
Table A                                 Table B
    _________________               _________________
    | A   | 2015-10-4               | B   | 2015-11-6
    | B   | 2015-11-4               | C   | 2015-05-4
    | C   | 2015-05-6               | D   | 2015-05-8
    | D   | 2015-05-7               | C   | 2015-05-5
```

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will get all letters from table B that has a date less than table A and any letter that doesn't exist in table B.

This is what I have so far

```
    SELECT      *
    FROM        A q JOIN 
                B c ON q.Letter = c.Letter AND q.Date > c.Date OR c.Letter IS NULL
```

This returns C but I can't have it return A also. It's confusing to me trying to join and compare tables still.

I do not want duplicate rows, the results I would be expecting would return

```
| A   | 2015-10-4 
| C   | 2015-05-6
```

**EDIT**

I'm running into an issue now where if I have a case like this

```
        Table A                           Table B
    _________________               _________________
    | A   | 2015-10-4               | B   | 2015-11-6
    | B   | 2015-11-4               | C   | 2015-05-4
    | C   | 2015-05-6               | D   | 2015-05-8
    | D   | 2015-05-7               | C   | 2015-05-5
                                    | C   | 2015-05-7
```

It will still return C for some reason.  Using `a.date > max(b.date)` doesn't work because max can't used that way. And I want to assume the max date can be anywhere in the table in table B.

So now my new results would be

```
| A   | 2015-10-4
```

But I am getting A and C still.

Comment: You should post your desired result, so we can understand if you want duplicated rows, which dates, etc

Comment: @Lamak Edited with expected results! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.letter, A.[Date]
FROM dbo.TableA A
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB B
    ON A.letter = B.letter
WHERE B.[Date] < A.[Date] OR B.letter IS NULL;
```

**UPDATE**

You should have explained your requirements as: "get all letters from table B in which every date is lesser than...."

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.letter, A.[Date]
FROM dbo.TableA A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT letter, MAX([Date]) [Date]
           FROM dbo.TableB
           GROUP BY letter) B
    ON A.letter = B.letter
WHERE B.[Date] < A.[Date] OR B.letter IS NULL;
```

Comment: Oh man, I can't believe I looked over something that simple. For some reason I couldn't wrap my mind around it.  I originally has the Date<Date in the `ON` part and checking for null was the only thing in the WHERE.  This did the trick! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited my question, I ran into a special case I wasn't expecting. Any insight on why this is happening would be great!

Comment: Thanks! I guess I never thought about that case until I started entering in some dummy data.  I've actually learned a ton on how joins and subqueries can work.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a UNION / UNION ALL, so that you get the result subset for the first condition + the ones for the second one.
Something similar to this should do the job:

```
sqlite> create table A (letter, my_date);
sqlite> create table B (letter, my_date);
sqlite> insert into A values ('A', '2015-10-04');
sqlite> insert into A values ('B', '2015-11-04');
sqlite> insert into A values ('C', '2015-05-06');
sqlite> insert into A values ('D', '2015-05-07');
sqlite> insert into B values ('B', '2015-11-06');
sqlite> insert into B values ('C', '2015-05-04');
sqlite> insert into B values ('D', '2015-05-08');
sqlite> insert into B values ('C', '2015-05-05');
A           2015-10-04
sqlite> select B.* from A, B where A.letter = B.letter and B.my_date < A.my_date UNION ALL select A.* from A where not exists (select 1 from B where B.letter=A.letter);
letter      my_date
----------  ----------
C           2015-05-04
C           2015-05-05
A           2015-10-04
```